# execute python from javascript

Tags: javascript, python

i'm newbie on python, so i'm trying to execute a script python from a javascript.

my script python should to create some directories and files.

**python:**

```
import os
#insert project name
name_project = raw_input("give the name of project :")
#create new ionic project
os.system('ionic start '+name_project+' blank')
#access to the project directory
os.chdir(name_project)
#create new platform
os.system('ionic platform add android')
```

**HTML :**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
   
  
</head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<body>

<button  id="home" onclick="runscript()" >save</button>
<script type="text/javascript">


function runscript(){

  $.ajax({

    url: 'myfile.py'

 
  });
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**webservice python:**

```
    import sys
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler


HandlerClass = SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
ServerClass  = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
Protocol     = "HTTP/1.0"

if sys.argv[1:]:
    port = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
    port = 9000
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', port)

HandlerClass.protocol_version = Protocol
httpd = (ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass))

sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()

print "Serving HTTP on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "..."

httpd.serve_forever()
```

the problem now is, when i click on the button "save" nothing appear. but the script is correct and it running if i execute it alone.

if any body have an idea thx

Comment: Please do a search before asking on SO. The question I marked this as a duplicate of was the first search result, by placing this question's title in Google.

Comment: i post the question because i don't found the solution. i google it but no success. it never resolved. so if any body have solution